# Openfire - cannot access 9090

Tags: ubuntu, openfire

I has been installed the openfire on Ubuntu 13.04:

```
sudo dpkg -i openfire_3.8.2_all.deb
(Reading database ... 219476 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace openfire 3.8.2 (using openfire_3.8.2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement openfire ...
Setting up openfire (3.8.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
```

after I reboot server. Next I run

```
sudo services openfire start
```

and tried localhost:9090 - This webpage is not available

```
ps -ef | grep openfire
loader    4319  3665  0 14:30 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto openfire
```

next command not showing port 9090:

```
netstat -tulpn
```

I tried in /etc/openfire/openfire.xml set my IP

```
<interface>12.34.56.78</interface>
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/openfire restart
```

The http://[localhost]:9090, http://[myip]:9090 not working too.
I tried chage port to another - same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In file /etc/init.d/openfire first lines of script try detect JAVA_HOME. But I have installed many java versions  and this variable is not exported. Instead I added this line

```
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

and Openfire started.

Comment: is it possible to share # Attempt to locate JAVA_HOME line?